# Streaming YouTube video from Android to Samsung TV with AllShare API

Tags: stream, development-environment, samsung-smart-tv

Question: I want to develop an app to stream the **youtube video** from ANDROID DEVICE to the Samsung Smart TV.

Already tried: I have been successful in developing an app which is streaming the local contents of the android device to the Samsung Smart TV using Samsung AllShare.

Problems: Using Samsung AllShare development API "**youtube video**" is not getting streamed to the Samsung Smart TV. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

For those who don't know: AllShare is the API used in developing app which is used to stream the contents of your android device to the Smart TV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube doesn't use AllShare ([DLNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Living_Network_Alliance)) to share to Samsung TV because that's will break some laws (license maybe) you maybe see also when using Screen Mirroring/AllShare Cast/[Miracast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracast) that some VOD application won't mirrored to TV.

Youtube using [DIAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIscovery_And_Launch) as the share protocol with TV and it makes the TV to launch the Youtube installed application in the TV to play selected videos, so the streaming will be done by the TV, with this mechanism there will be no issue in media license for mobile and TV.

Comment: thanks for the reply @imkrishna but there are some streaming applications like TWONKY BEAM which are very easily streaming the youtube stuff to the tv

Comment: moreover the TWONKY BEAM is not launching the youtube app on smart tv it is just streaming the video from the video phone

Comment: Not sure but twonky seems like iMediaShare apps, they can get the direct video link from sources (using special API like keepvid.com) and send them to TV/Device. using this it's possible to play the video since the player actually support http streaming (like passing url on VLC). If you can get the direct link to video you can use the DLNA MediaRenderer protocol to do that

Comment: @imkrishna : exactly that is the problem i am facing how can i get the direct link of the youtube video ...... i have tried with the RTSP links of youtube videos but they are of very low quality and those rtsp links are getting streamed to the samsung smart tv....                                     SECONDLY u said that TWONKY BEAM is using KEEPVID.COM so u mean to say that first twonky beam is downloading the whole video and then streaming it ??????

Comment: no i mean, they maybe have special API from youtube like keepvid had. Big players sometimes have API that not opened for public

Comment: @imkrishna: earlier u told about DIAL,I HAVE STUDIED ABOUT IT but it is used to launch the desired application on SMART tv from your smart phone... which i does not want. i only want the video to be streamed to the tv as twonky beam is doing....i have been trying about more than a month to find a logic abouyt it but not been able to ....

Comment: @imkrishna:any help will be greatly appreciated because i have been really stuck on it since long time now .....